# Enable SSH2 on MAMP 4.4.1 PHP 7.2.1

Tags: php, mamp

I am using php7.2.1 on MAMP 4.4.1 and was trying to enable SSH2 but couldn't succeed.

Anyone, who have already configured SSH2 on PHP7.2.1 then please guide me through.

Thanks

Aziz